# How to filter Sql type string

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I know how to use filter in sql with decimal type, but this time I am working with string type.

- I need to filter anything greater than "3 hrs" or "180 min"
- I was able to get it to filter anything greater than "3 hrs"
- But not able to filter anything greater than 180 mins

here is screenshot of output for this table.

[image]

Here is SQL select statement and it is working

```
SELECT EVENTID,
       STARTDATETIME,
       F_NAME,
       DURATIONHM,
       NUM_PEOPLE

  FROM EVENT_FACT
  where DURATIONHM > '3 hrs'
```

Comment: stinky thing to make you do...  that should be a number of course - perhaps parsing the string back to its constituent number of minutes is a good starting point.

Comment: Are you able to add a column for storing duration in minutes? This will be pretty messy otherwise.

Comment: do I look up some formula to convert 1 min into hrs format?

Comment: @egrunin that would be last option, could be done, I hope so.

Comment: @HolgerBrandt I am front end user not database admin sorry I wouldn't know.

Comment: @user1512440, The problem is that every Database Engine has different syntax for string manipulation.  Therefore, without knowing which DB Engine you are using, we can't provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me, I guess I know now that I need to go with @egrunin's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write the query the way that you want to.  You need to store the duration in minutes, as a number, and then use:

```
where duration >= 3*60
```

You can, with a bunch of effort, create a view that parses the string to get the minutes.  In some databases, you can also convert such a string into a time or interval data type, which gets you further along.

However, what you have discovered is that storing the duration as a string does not meet the query requirements that you have on the field.  (You would discover the same thing if you tried to order by duration.)